# jQuery ajax calling javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function-calls

I am using jQuery and Ajax.

My MainFile has the following code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="Myscript.js">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'ajax.php',
                    success: function(data){
                        $("#response").html(data);
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>

    <body>
        <div id="response">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My ajax.php get the sample data

```
...
MyScript.js has the following

function display (text,corner)
{

}
..
```

I have Myscript.js. In this, I have a function called `display(text,corner)`. I have to call this function after executing ajax.php.

How do I do it in jQuery for the above code?

Is it possible to decide the order of execution after ajax.php and make call for `display(text,corner)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should invoke the `display` function in the callback function of the Ajax Request, like such:

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url: 'ajax.php',
    success: function(data){
        display(data, /* your other parameter, corner */); //Invoking your data function
    } 
});
```

In the above case, `data` is the response that is received from `ajax.php`