# Rebind Menu Js after Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am building an online URL auction tool. Below is the results page after a user enters a URL to purchase. When this results page is called 2 other results pages are being created, but they take a while so what I’m trying to do is setup the menu bar to read ‘Loading’  on both buttons and the href to #. I then use setInterval to poll every 2 secs, checking if the second file has been created.  Once it has, the success callback reloads the buttons to active hrefs and labels them [‘Find Out Whois’ ,and ‘Appraisal’] rather than 'Loading'.

**Question:** How can I rebind the menu bar js so that it works after the ajax call? Ive being reading SO on this exact topic but failing at using [.live()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8594408/jquery-reload-javascript-file-after-an-ajax-request), [.on()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380005/reload-document-readyfunction-after-ajax-page-is-reloaded),  [display()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392658/jquery-ajax-calling-javascript-function) , and [more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722921/loading-javascripts-in-ajax-callbacks?rq=1)…

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Domain Auctions R US</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
        <style>
            body{
                background-repeat:no-repeat;
                background-color:#fff;
            }

            span.reference{
                position:fixed;
                left:10px;
                bottom:10px;
                font-size:12px;
            }
            span.reference a{
                color:#aaa;
                text-transform:uppercase;
                text-decoration:none;
                text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #000;
                margin-right:30px;
            }
            span.reference a:hover{
                color:#ddd;
            }
            ul.sdt_menu{
                margin-left:auto;
                margin-right:auto;
                margin-top:0px;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
<body>
<br/><br/><br/><br/>
        <div class="content" id="content">
            <ul id="sdt_menu" class="sdt_menu">
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><!-- When the other two results pages are ready, this needs to be a real link -->
                        <img src="../images/googleMap.jpg" alt=""/>
                        <span class="sdt_active"></span>
                        <span class="sdt_wrap">
                            <span class="sdt_link">Loading</span>
                            <span class="sdt_descr">Page not yet available</span>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="worth.html">
                        <img src="../images/pawnShop.jpg" alt=""/>
                        <span class="sdt_active"></span>
                        <span class="sdt_wrap">
                            <span class="sdt_link">Loading</span>
                            <span class="sdt_descr">Page not yet available</span>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>   
            </ul>
        </div>

        <h1>The URL you are searching for is currenly TAKEN.</h1>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $('#sdt_menu > li').bind('mouseenter',function(){ //LINE SWITCH 1
                    var $elem = $(this);
                    $elem.find('img')
                         .stop(true)
                         .animate({
                            'width':'170px',
                            'height':'170px',
                            'left':'0px'
                         },400,'easeOutBack')
                         .andSelf()
                         .find('.sdt_wrap')
                         .stop(true)
                         .animate({'top':'140px'},500,'easeOutBack')
                         .andSelf()
                         .find('.sdt_active')
                         .stop(true)
                         .animate({'height':'170px'},300,function(){
                        var $sub_menu = $elem.find('.sdt_box');
                        if($sub_menu.length){
                            var left = '170px';
                            if($elem.parent().children().length == $elem.index()+1)
                                left = '-170px';
                            $sub_menu.show().animate({'left':left},200);
                        }   
                    });
                }).bind('mouseleave',function(){ //LINE SWITCH 2
                    var $elem = $(this);
                    var $sub_menu = $elem.find('.sdt_box');
                    if($sub_menu.length)
                        $sub_menu.hide().css('left','0px');

                    $elem.find('.sdt_active')
                         .stop(true)
                         .animate({'height':'0px'},300)
                         .andSelf().find('img')
                         .stop(true)
                         .animate({
                            'width':'0px',
                            'height':'0px',
                            'left':'85px'},400)
                         .andSelf()
                         .find('.sdt_wrap')
                         .stop(true)
                         .animate({'top':'25px'},500);
                });
            });

                var myVar=setInterval(function(){ajax_request()},2000);
                  function ajax_request() {
                  $.ajax({
                  type: "GET",
                  url: "http://exampleServer/urlID/4b49d2/index.html",
                  dataType: "script",
                  success: function() {
                  $('#conn').load("ajax-loader.html");


                  clearInterval(myVar);
                  },
                  error: function() {
                    alert("error");
                  }
                });
                }
        </script>

</body>
</html>
```

**ajax-loader.html**

```
<ul id="sdt_menu" class="sdt_menu">
                <li>
                    <a href="../map.html">
                        <img src="../images/googleMap.jpg" alt=""/>
                        <span class="sdt_active"></span>
                        <span class="sdt_wrap">
                            <span class="sdt_link">Find out Whois</span>
                            <span class="sdt_descr">Map of Who Owns Domain</span>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="worth.html">
                        <img src="../images/pawnShop.jpg" alt=""/>
                        <span class="sdt_active"></span>
                        <span class="sdt_wrap">
                            <span class="sdt_link">Appraisal</span>
                            <span class="sdt_descr">Real Time Value of Domain</span>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>   
            </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be simple enough, using `.on()` instead of `.bind()`:

```
$('#content')
    .on('mouseenter', '.sdt_menu > li', function() {
    })
    .on('mouseleave', '.sdt_menu > li', function() {
    })
```

Note that `.bind()` and `.on()` work differently and a simple rename doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you for your post. I tried that, and it works except for the menu bar animation is non responsive after ajax. Specifically, I commented 'LINE SWITCH 1 and 2' where I switched 'bind' for 'on'. Or is that not what I should be doing?

Comment: @Chris Yes, that's where you should make the change ... if the animation is not responsive, how do you know it works though, because nearly all that code inside is about animation?

Comment: You didn't just switch `bind` for `on` did you? The arguments are different, and need to match what @Jack posted, as well as changing the parent jQuery selector.

Comment: @Chris take note of what jmoerdyk said.

Comment: @Jack, I meant by working that the Menu Titles changed and on mouseover they point to the correct urls now. However, I only switched the words -- not argument structure. Ill try that now. Thank you and jmoerdyk for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use delegate to bind an event to all current and future elements:

http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Comment: He's using jQuery 1.8.1, [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) should be used instead of `.delegate()`